# Omnetpp INET error: Mobility position is not a finite number after initialize

Tags: omnet++, inet

Very new to omnet but I've been trying to set up a wireless mesh on top of StandardHost. While it compiles well, when the simulation starts I get this error:

```
Mobility position is not a finite number after initialize (x=-nan,y=-nan,z=-nan) -- in module (inet::StationaryMobility) Net.node[0].mobility (id=12), during network initialization
```

Below are my `package.ned`, `omnetpp.ini` and `mwe.ned`.

If I set up the `Node` submodules of `Net` one by one and add a fixed property `@display("p=...")` to each one of them then it works. Setting them up more parametrically i.e. `node[size]: Node;` it fails to execute the simulation with the above error.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

#### package.ned

```
package mwe;
```

#### omnetpp.ini

```
[General]
network = Net
*.radioMedium.typename = "Ieee802154NarrowbandScalarRadioMedium"
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.typename = "Ieee802154NarrowbandScalarRadio"
**.wlan[0].typename = "Ieee802154NarrowbandInterface"
*.host*.ipv4.arp.typename = "GlobalArp"
*.size = 2
```

#### mwe.ned

```
package mwe;

import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
import inet.physicallayer.unitdisk.UnitDiskRadioMedium;
import inet.physicallayer.contract.packetlevel.IRadioMedium;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;

module Node extends StandardHost
{
    parameters:
        numWlanInterfaces = default(1);
}

network Net
{
    parameters:
        int size = default(1);
    submodules:
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
        radioMedium: <default("UnitDiskRadioMedium")> like IRadioMedium;
        node[size]: Node;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, with the exact same error message.

I solved it by setting the following parameters:

```
*.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMaxX = 650m
*.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
*.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMaxY = 500m
*.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
*.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m
*.host[*].mobility.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
```

I found the solution reading through the `MobilityBase::setInitialPosition` method: with a minimal configuration, `getRandomPosition` is called, and uses those values as min and max for the random.